# C# listbox array trouble

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging, listbox, freeze

All. I am creating a program that takes a list of teams as a string array and compares it to a .txt file that contains a list of all the World Series winners and determines how many times a team has won the World Series based off which Team you select in a list box.

My code is throwing 0 errors and the first time I ran the program and selected a team and clicked the button it showed the messagebox displaying the team name and how many times they won. After that, whenever I would choose a team again and click the button, nothing happens. It just freezes. I have to then stop debugging. What could have possibly went went wrong? Any thoughts and advice?

```
namespace WorldSeriesWinners
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
        string[] inputTeams = 
        { 
          "Boston Americans", "New York Giants", "Chicago White Sox","Chicago Cubs",
          "Pittsburgh Pirates", "Philadelphia Athletics","Boston Red Sox", "Boston Braves",
          "Cincinatti Reds", "Cleveland Indians","Brooklyn Dodgers",
          "New York Yankees", "Washington Senators", 
          "St. Louis Cardinals","Detroit Tigers", "Milwaukee Braves",
          "Los Angeles Dodgers", "New York Mets", "Baltimore Orioles",
          "Oakland Athletics", "Philadelphia Phillies", "Kansas City Royals", "Minnesota Twins", "Toronto Blue Jays", 
          "Atlanta Braves", "Florida Marlins", "Arizona Diamondbacks", "Anaheim Angels", "San Francisco Giants"
        };

    string[] worldseriesWinners = new string[104];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(inputTeams);
    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");
        List<string> inputTeams = new List<string>();
        string selectedTeam;

        while (!champFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            inputTeams.Add(champFile.ReadLine());
        }
        while (listBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            selectedTeam = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        selectedTeam = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var count = File.ReadLines("WorldSeriesWinners.txt").Count(x => x.Contains(selectedTeam));

        if (count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series " + count + " times! ");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has never won the World Series.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through this code.. I am curious to what's happening in your first while loop start off by `1` telling us what the error is

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. When I select the first item in the list box and hit the button to show the message box that displays how may times the team won the World Series, it works. If I select any other team in the list box the program just freezes and I have to stop debugging.

Comment: well look at your code.. for starters.. perhaps you need to look at this line of code `StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");`  opening it the first time is fine.. but when do you close and or dispose of the `champFIle` object..?

Comment: May not be proper practice but changing the `while (listBox1.SelectedIndex!=0)` to `if (listBox1.SelectedIndex !=0)` seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is never going to work unless you always pick the first item in the list as your code that does this

```
while (listBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
    selectedTeam = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

will keep running forever since if you pick any other item in the listbox besides the first entry, the listBox1.SelectedIndex will never be 0 and it will loop forever.  There's no reason to have a while loop to read the selected item.

Comment: Thank you. changing the while to `if (listBox1.SelectedINdex !=0)`  seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the stream when you are done with it

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");

 ...
     champFile.Close();
}
```

best practice is to use a `using` statement

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeriesWinners.txt"))
    {

 ...
     }
}
```

you can test this by wrapping your `File.OpenText` in a `try` statement. and breaking the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
using(StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeriesWinners.txt")){
...
}
```

Comment: It is correct that it is best practice to close the stream, but this isn't the source of the bug; there is an infinite while loop. The stream is a local variable which will go out of scope at the end of the method and eventually get garbage collected, which will close the stream. There is a potential file locking issue, depending on how the file got opened. Personally, I'd rather see the file opened as read-only than worry about the stream not being closed; that would avoid any chance of file corruption by accidental write and solve file locking issues into the bargain.